# DataFusion How to use BigQuery Execute object for deleting records prior loading?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

Let's say I have a BigQuery table where CSV data is being loaded into it.
A column with the unique CSV filename will be used as the filter for deleting data.

DELETE FROM "project"."name_dataset".CSVTable WHERE FileName = 'client_202209011415'

There isn't enough documentation and examples on how to use the BigQuery Execute object. I tried multiple options without any luck.

A portion of the log that caught my attention
"code" : 404,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Not found: Dataset :<name_dataset> was not found in location US",
"reason" : "notFound"
} ],
"message" : "Not found: Dataset :<name_dataset> was not found in location US",
"status" : "NOT_FOUND"

What is correct way to reference a BigQuery object with this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Job Location' config property that defaults to 'US'. Based on the error you pasted, you will likely need to set this to the location of your dataset.